# githubを用いた質問方法

Tags: github

自作の開発アプリで困っているところがあり解決策が分からないので、githubにコードを上げてそちらを参照していただいて問題点を指摘して頂きたいと思っています。

そこで、お聞きしたいのはgithubには質問機能があるのでしょうか。
「この部分でこうするとこのようなエラーが出るから解決策教えてください」といったことを投稿できる掲示板のようなものがgithubにあるか知りたいです。

Comment: issuesが使えるのでは https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-issues

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「問題点を指摘して頂きたい」は、誰に指摘されることを想定していますか？ まさかスタックオーバーフロー閲覧者とかは想定していませんよね。確かにIssueを使うことはできますが、誰にも見てもらえないなら解決策とはなっていないような気がします。

Comment: 最近クローズされた[よくわからない隙間がでてくる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90823/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e9%9a%99%e9%96%93%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b)なんかが悪い例です。スタックオーバーフローではこのような質問方法は受け付けていません。

Answer (score 1):

ここスタックオーバーフローのようなプログラマ向け質問サービスで質問した上で、質問文の補足情報としてGitHubプロジェクトへのリンクを貼るのが良いかと思います。

質問文でなく回答文の例になりますが、 [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65829/2808)がそのイメージになります。

ここでは、回答として成立する文章を本文に記載した上で "サンプル実装" のリンク先(GitHub)にフレームワークを含めた完動するコードを記載しています。

質問の場合にも、同じような手段を採れるかと思います。

---

> お聞きしたいのはgithubには質問機能があるのでしょうか。

ありませんし、そのようなことを行うのは一般的ではありません。

[Issues](https://docs.github.com/ja/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-issues)や[Discussions](https://docs.github.com/ja/discussions/collaborating-with-your-community-using-discussions/about-discussions)という機能は、リポジトリオーナー(今回の場合 **あなた) に対して** 質問する場合には利用できますが、 **あなたが** 質問するのには適していません。

回答候補者に対して、そこに質問が存在するということを通知する術がないからです。

Comment: 特にDiscussionsなら（別にIssueでも構わないですが）リポジトリのオーナーがリポジトリのコミュニティメンバーに質問することは可能です。[コミュニティの動向に影響を与える決定をフォロー](https://docs.github.com/ja/discussions)なんかはその例かと。ただ、質問文へのコメントにも書きましたが「githubにコードを上げて」という行動からはそのリポジトリにコミュニティメンバーが存在しないことが想定されます…。

Answer (score 1):

「コードの分量」、および「誰に向けて質問するのか」次第だと思います。

---

- GitHub は主にソースコードの履歴を管理するためのサービスです。
  (一時的に) 少量のコードを開示するのが目的で、履歴も必要なければ GitHub の [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) を使う方がより手軽です。
- 例えばメールの本文や Yahoo! 知恵袋などのWebサービスで、コードがプレーンテキストで見づらくなってしまう場合に GitHub (や Gist) を使うのは選択肢の一つです。
  ただし、「詳しいコードはリンク先にあります」形式の質問は、読み手にとっては面倒なので読まれない可能性があります。
- コードが複数のファイルで構成される = いわゆる「プロジェクト」の単位になるような分量だと、GitHub にアップしたくなりますが、こちらも前述の理由と同様に (ダウンロードが) 面倒なので読まれない可能性があります。
- 他の回答やコメント欄で GitHub の Issue や Discussions の機能について触れられていますが、GitHub 上で何かしらのアクションを行うには GitHub のアカウントが必要です。